# Azure pipeline Stage and Job Dependencies

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create two pipeline templates used to integrate with an API which 1) installs an application 2) deploys the application to some devices that the API administers. The install template handles the install and gets back an application ID that the deploy template will require in order to deploy the app. There is no way to query the API later on to get the app ID so I must make it available for the install template for use later on by the deploy template. The install task will be called once, but the deploy task can be called multiple times for different device "rings".

I need to support the following scenario where the deploy template can have a dependency on both a job in the current stage, and can be dependent on the same job in a later stage.

```
stages:
- stage: NonProd
  jobs:
  - template: install.yml@pipeline_template
  - template: deploy.yml@pipeline_template  

- stage: Prod
  dependsOn: NonProd
  jobs:
  - template: deploy.yml@pipeline_template
```

I read we can do create these types of dependencies now [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#azure-pipelines-1), but is it possible to set the dependencies to come from either a prior stage or a prior job?

I considered trying to combine these into a single template, but unfortunately if the same version of the app already exists the install step will not provide the app id back, just an error.

Answer (score 4):

According to the update in 5/4 [Jobs can access output variables from previous stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#jobs-can-access-output-variables-from-previous-stages)

You can currently specify that a stage run based on the value of an output variable set in a previous stage.

This is used in conditions of a stage.

> but is it possible to set the dependencies to come from either a
>   prior stage or a prior job?

You can't directly depend on a job from another stage.

But, **when you define multiple jobs in a single stage, you can specify dependencies between them.** Pipelines must contain at least one job with no dependencies.

Besides, you can also depend one stage on others.